# Else If batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to auto-silent Update an air application with a native installer, so I made this batch file :

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (
taskkill /IM Application.exe
taskkill /IM adl.exe
wmic product where name="Application" call uninstall /nointeractive
"%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\com.application\Local Store\Application.exe" -silent -eulaAccepted -location "\%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\" -desktopShortcut
"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Applicaion\Application.exe"
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe 
) ELSE (
taskkill /IM Application.exe 
taskkill /IM adl.exe
wmic product where name="Application" call uninstall /nointeractive
"%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\com.Application\Local Store\Application.exe" -silent -eulaAccepted -location "\%PROGRAMFILES%\" -desktopShortcut
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Application\Application.exe"
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe )
```

And I tested it on a 64bit windows, so the %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%" does exist, and it uninstall the software, but without installing the new one, and it does not work at all on windows 32bit

Comment: You've spelt `\Applicaion\...` incorrectly on the installation line in the `if` branch. Does that help with problem 1?

Comment: And for the second one, have you tried `echo`ing the path out to make sure it actually points where you want to go?

Comment: no I just changed the name before posting this, I always double check the names, 100% it was right, and no I didn't but @Endordo's answer seems exactly like the thing that I need,

Comment: Cool. Well upvote him then ;-)

Comment: The installation : `Failed (consult log)`, I guess it's because of this, `%HOMEPATH%`, the link starts with \User\ and not C:\User\. What I really don't understand, is that the installation was working before, when I made it just for 64bit ...

Comment: My bad ! -destination should be just "%PROGRAMFOLDER%" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
IF DEFINED PROGRAMFILES(X86) (SET "PROGRAMFOLDER=%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%") ELSE SET "PROGRAMFOLDER=%PROGRAMFILES%"
taskkill /IM Application.exe
taskkill /IM adl.exe
wmic product where name="Application" call uninstall /nointeractive
"%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\com.application\Local Store\Application.exe" -silent -eulaAccepted -location "\%PROGRAMFOLDER%\" -desktopShortcut
"%PROGRAMFOLDER%\Application\Application.exe"
taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, can you just change the -location to `"%PROGRAMFOLDER%"` incase anyone will need something like this.